# Cannot see selected text android AppcompactSpinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I have put an app compact spinner in my application. I am unable to see the selected text(I think this is because the colour of the selected text becomes white, i.e same as the background colour). I am able to see the text in the dropdown.

**support-design - 23.3.0**

**minSdkVersion: 15**

**targetSdkVersion 23**

My Spinner code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/university_spinner">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

See the images below to understand the error

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try it or not ?

Comment: Hi Harshad thanks for your answers. I am not an home. I will come, try out the answer and let you know.

Comment: if you try my answer then tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look Here is step By step solution.

**Step : 1 )  define AppCompactSpinner in your xml file**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/university_spinner">
    </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

**Step : 2 ) create two different xml file.**

```
       xml file : spinner_item.xml

               <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:id="@android:id/text1"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:textColor="#000000" />


       xml file : spinner_dropdown_item.xml

                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:id="@android:id/text1"
                     style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
                     android:singleLine="true"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:ellipsize="marquee"
                     android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

**Step : 3 ) java code :** 
               declaration

```
AppCompatSpinner appCompatSpinner;
String[] skills = {"Australian National University","Monash University"};

           inside OnCreate


appCompatSpinner = (AppCompatSpinner)findViewById(R.id.university_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter staticAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, skills);
    staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    appCompatSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
```

**Step : 4 ) Without Select Text output :**

[image]

**Step : 5 ) With Select Text output :**

[image]

Comment: Hi thanx for the answer. Do you have idea on what is causing this issue? Is this a bug?

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia your `AppCompatSpinner` and and `TextView` text-Color both are `#FFFFFF` so the text is not display.

Comment: Great answer with explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Hi found out the problem was in the file android.R.layout.simpler_spinner_item as it had not given the text-Color. So I just copied that code and gave a black text-color to it.

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
 style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```